# How to clone/duplicate contents of file-visiting buffer in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Say I have opened a file `foo.c` in a buffer A. Now I want to open a new buffer B which contains the same contents as A, but with no connection to the file `foo.c`. How can this be done?

Comment: Copy and paste?

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, I can open a new buffer, to which I copy-paste the contents of the old buffer, but I thought there would be a more lazy way to do it considering that what I want to do is essentially to copy the buffer itself.

Comment: You can write a quick macro, searching for "emacs clone buffer" will turn up solutions.

Comment: Hm, yeah "clone" was a better term than duplicate. Turns out there is a command `clone-buffer`, but for some reason it only works on buffers that are not operating on a file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was already answered at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-can-i-quickly-toggle-between-a-file-and-a-scratch-buffer-having-the-same-m

Comment: @tripleee: It is OK for different users to post essentially the same question on different SE sites. If the same user does that then a comment asking not to do it is appropriate, but that is still not a reason for closing the question. A duplicate question on the *same* site can be closed as a dup.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
 (defun my-copy-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (get-buffer-create "NEWBUF")
  (copy-to-buffer "NEWBUF" (point-min) (point-max)))
```